# How to resolve "Module @nuxt/image is disabled due to incompatibility issues" error in nuxt2

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-module

I am using nuxt version `2.15.8` in my project. I want to install and use [`NuxtImage`](https://v0.image.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation) module in my project. Acoording to its docs, running `npm install -D @nuxt/image` command must install the version that is compatible to nuxt-2. But after that I see this warning in my command line when I use `npm run dev` command:

[image: NuxtImage-warning]

Why this happens, when the docs is saying that version is compatible with nuxt-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/nuxt/image#nuxt-2

> **Nuxt 2** Note: This branch is for Nuxt 3 compatible module. Checkout v0
> branch for Nuxt 2 support. (Announcement)

You should use `v0` branch for Nuxt 2. So install it with:

```
npm i @nuxt/image@v0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think that must be mentioned in the docs. I mean that the command in the [docs](https://v0.image.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation) page is **not** correct (```npm install -D @nuxt/image```) and must be substituted with ```npm i @nuxt/image@v0``` or something like that!